# create a specific class type from a variable and set data into the class

Tags: c#

I have a project which I am working on currently and I am facing a problem at the moment.

What I am trying to figure out is how to load a class variable with data so I can create a specific type of a class using that variable:

```
private Vehicle vehicleDetails;
vehicleDetails = new Vehicle();

public Order(string ordLine, string vehLine)
{
    orderDetails = new JobDetails(ordLine);
    string temp = vehLine.Substring(0, 1);

    if (temp == "P")
    {
        vehicleDetails.vehicleDetails.splitter(vehLine);
        vehicleDetails = new PersonalUseCars();
    }
}
```

An example of vehLine will be something like this - "P-LU12SAK-Ford-6m-...." In the variable temp we store the first letter which is the type of car we want to create. The vehicle class looks like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CarGarageSoftware
{
    class Vehicle
    {
        public string type;
        public string Lplate;
        public string Make;
        public string LMOT;
        public string Esize;
        public string Transmission;
        public string Mileage;
        public string FuleT;

        public Vehicle()
        { 
        } 

        public virtual string returnString()
        {
            string temp = type + "-" + Lplate + "-" + Make + "-" + LMOT + "-" + Esize + "-" + Transmission + "-" + Mileage + "-" + FuleT;
            return temp;
        }

        public virtual void splitter(string x)
        {
            string[] strings = x.Split("-");
            type = strings[0];
            Lplate = strings[1];
            Make = strings[2];
            LMOT = strings[3];
            Esize = strings[4];
            Transmission = strings[5];
            Mileage = strings[6];
            FuleT = strings[7];  
        }
    }

    class PersonalUseCars : Vehicle
    {
        public override string returnString()
        {
            string temp = type + "-" + Lplate + "-" + Make + "-" + LMOT + "-" + Esize + "-" + Transmission + "-" + Mileage + "-" + FuleT ;
            return temp;
        }
    }

    class BusinessCars : Vehicle
    {
        public string CompanyN;
        public string CompanyA;
        public string FleetN;

        public override string returnString()
        {
            string temp = type + "-" + Lplate + "-" + Make + "-" + LMOT + "-" + Esize + "-" + Transmission + "-" + Mileage + "-" + FuleT + "-" + CompanyN + "-" + CompanyA + "-" + FleetN;
            return temp;
        }
    }

    class WorkVehicle : Vehicle
    {
        public string CompanyN;
        public string CompanyA;
        public string purpose;
        public string Type;

        public override string returnString()
        {
            string temp = type + "-" + Lplate + "-" + Make + "-" + LMOT + "-" + Esize + "-" + Transmission + "-" + Mileage + "-" + FuleT + "-" + CompanyN+"-"+CompanyA+"-"+purpose ;
            return temp;
        }
    }

    class Motobikes : Vehicle
    {
    }
}
```

I want `vehicleDetails` to return the right data into the class, and when the right type of vehicle is created I would like to load the new vehicle with the right data from vehLine, so that the class contains the right values.

I have tried using different techniques but I am just a beginner so nothing comes to my mind.

Comment: Are you looking for the [factory pattern](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/factory-method-design-pattern-in-c-sharp/) ?